# Clear voice guidance queue

Tags: android, here-api

When I start several guidance here map speak several time but i want that it speak only for the last guidance so how can I clear the queue of voiceguidance before that it speak ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to "clear the queue". If you want to control audio playback, then you need to implement an interface `AudioPlayerDelegate`.
Details: https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/topics/audio-management.html